# iTunes Connect: In App Purchases - Developer Action Needed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

So basically I did this:

1. Prepared and uploaded the build with iAPs (they was ready for sale at that moment) to App page in iTunes Connect. Status was "Ready to submit"
2. Then after some time, It was Rejected and I noticed that the iAPs was also in Rejected state, the iAPs status was "Developer Action Needed", and "Rejected" in detail info.
3. I tried to send to review App with build and iAPs at the same time, so they both was in "Waiting for Review" status. And after some time, it was Rejected, Review Team said that iAPs not responding. I think because iAPs was not selected in App Info (they were not there).
4. After that, I decided to try change the iAPs details, and sent all Rejected iAPs again to Review. The App itself remains in "Prepare for review" state, i didn't sent it.

Now I don't know what steps should I do. Currently App in "Prepare for Upload" state and all iAPs  in "Developer Action Needed" state, the alert inside says:
**"Your In-App Purchase has been returned. You must modify or delete the highlighted item."**

And the details for iAPs Rejection also says:
**"We have returned your IAP product/s to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the IAPs with the binary."**

Will be glad to to figure out this issue.

Comment: The in-app purchases will be reviewed in conjunction with the application binary; So when you are ready submit a new application binary and they will review it and the in-app purchases

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay, so all my iAPs should stay in "Developer Action Needed" status and I just need to upload new binary, right?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, I will give it a try and say if it worked

Comment: So there are 2 solutions, 1) upload new binary and send it for review 2) If previous in some reason not working, delete and create again iAP

Comment: @Resty Did that worked, uploading new binary??

Comment: @Aanchal yes, it solved the problem!

Comment: Got same issue ... having older binary already release on AppStore, I added couple of new In Apps, now Apple wants new binary ... so I uploaded new binary (no new functionality added for the new In Apps, so this required hacky change to raise version of the app), new In Apps have still status "Develper Action Needed". I don't want to bother with plenty of hacky changes in order to change the state and allow resubmission, just because of Apple strange internal chaos...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the status of the iAPs to "Waiting for Review" by editing the description. You can add "." or delete a "." then save. This will change the status from "Developer Action Needed" to "Waiting for Review"

Now when you submit the new binary the iAPs will be submitted with it.

Comment: I did that and worked for some time but next day I had to do the same